# Pgadmin removes brackets in case when statements when not desired

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I try to create CASE WHEN statement with multiple values with OR and AND operators.

I have 3 statements that should give value 1 when at least one of them is true. Using brackets I ensure that I have 3 cases. Anyhow pgadmin removes brackets and I have finally 6 statements which will will equal to 0 as it can never be true (because of AND)

```
CASE
WHEN ((t2.ticket_completed_at = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day' AND t2.ticket_created_at <> CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')             
    OR (t2.ticket_deleted_at = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day' AND t2.ticket_created_at <> CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')                                                    
    OR (t2.ticket_canceled_at = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day' AND t2.ticket_created_at <> CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day')) THEN 1 
ELSE 0

Anyhow after puting this code into View in PGADMIN it removes brackets and  I receive


CASE
  WHEN t2.ticket_completed_at = ('now'::text::date - '1 day'::interval) AND t2.ticket_created_at <> ('now'::text::date - '1 day'::interval) 
  OR t2.ticket_deleted_at = ('now'::text::date - '1 day'::interval) AND t2.ticket_created_at <> ('now'::text::date - '1 day'::interval) 
  OR t2.ticket_canceled_at = ('now'::text::date - '1 day'::interval) AND t2.ticket_created_at <> ('now'::text::date - '1 day'::interval) THEN 1
ELSE 0
```

Comment: Which version of pgAdmin and what *exactly* are you doing? I never noticed it changes queries... The parenthesis however don't change anything as `AND` already takes precedence over `OR`. So if in the last one the line about `t2.ticket_completed_at` wasn't missing there'd be no difference. But you can shorten that a bit by extracting the comparison for the creation of the ticket and use `IN` instead of `OR`: `t2.ticket_created_at <> ('now'::text::date - '1 day'::interval) AND ('now'::text::date - '1 day'::interval) IN (t2.ticket_completed_at, t2.ticket_deleted_at, t2.ticket_canceled_at)`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "after inserting"? There is no `INSERT` statement in your question. You also mention you are using a CASE expression, but your code does not contain one either.

Comment: PG admin version is 4.9 but the problem should be in code itself

Comment: Maybe I get it now... You create a view where the expression is somewhere in the query that defines it. After you created it, in the SQL shown by pgAdmin for that view the expression is changed? Well, then there is no real problem here other than maybe loosing some readability if you consider your version more readable. As I already mentioned the expressions are equivalent so the meaning doesn't change.

Comment: Hey, I just splited it to separate case statements. I see your point with brackets.
Yes the expression was changed by pgadmin but because of your reason i think that brackets were not relevant. The question just out of curiosity how to combine OR and AND operators in one Case statement?